# Reverse operation of torch.unique

Tags: pytorch

In pytorch , unique (with return_count is True) operation do like this

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3] => ([1,2,3],[2,2,2])
```

Are there any reverse operations of torch.unique() ?
i.e Given a unique list and its count , return the original list like

```
([1,2,3],[2,2,2]) = > [1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include the `return inverse` parameter it will return the indices for where elements in the original input ended up in the returned unique list. Then you can use [take](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.take.html#torch.take) to create a new tensor.

```
test_tensor = torch.tensor([1,1,2,2,3,3])
items, inverse, counts = test_tensor.unique(return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
new_tensor = torch.take(items, inverse)
assert new_tensor.eq(test_tensor).all() # true
```

EDIT:
If you only have a list and the counts this code should give you what you want using [repeat](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html). Not sure if a pure pytorch function exists.

```
test_tensor = torch.tensor([1,1,2,2,3,3])
items, counts = test_tensor.unique(return_counts=True)

new_tensor = torch.tensor([], dtype=torch.int64)
for item, count in zip(items, counts):
    new_tensor = torch.cat((new_tensor, item.repeat(count)))

assert new_tensor.eq(test_tensor).all() # true
```

Comment: Acutally , I only can provide a list with its counts (which is provided by other process.), so no "inverse array" is exist.

Comment: @Exia edited answer, maybe someone else knows a better solution :)

Comment: since I use torch.trace to deploy on c++ application, for loop should be avoid

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [torch.repeat_interleave()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html). You can use it like this:

```py
 >>> x = torch.tensor([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
 >>> v, c = torch.unique(x, return_counts=True)
 >>> v, c
 (tensor([1, 2, 3]), tensor([2, 1, 3]))
 
 >>> torch.repeat_interleave(v, c)
 tensor([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```